# Limit of Multiple indirection

Tags: c++, c, pointers

What is maximum limit of using multiple indirection pointer declaration in C?

For example, as given below

```
int *******a;
```

What is the maximum limit of using `*` operator?

Comment: lower for human reader than for the compiler...

Comment: Why would there be a limit?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087113/how-many-levels-of-pointers-can-we-have/10087135#10087135

Comment: Note: in that context, * is not an operator. A maximum limit of the * operator depends on the type of the expression: for `int *******a;`, you can have expressions `a`, `*a`, `**a`, ..., `*******a`, but not `********a`.

Answer (score 0):

The upper limit is implementation specific, and not specified.