# Taking arrays as arguments with triple pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers

Please tell me the difference between functions accepting arrays using single, double or triple pointers.

Example code:

```
int visit(int ***A, int i, int j, int n, int m, int size) {
     (*A)[i][j] = -1;
     size++;
     if(i-1 >= 0 && j-1 >= 0 && (*A)[i-1][j-1] == 1) {
        size += visit(A, i-1, j-1, n, m, 0);
     }
     if(i-1 >= 0 && (*A)[i-1][j] == 1) {
         size += visit(A, i-1, j, n, m, 0);
     }
     if(i-1 >= 0 && j+1 < m && (*A)[i-1][j+1] == 1) {
         size += visit(A, i-1, j+1, n, m, 0);
     }
     if(j-1 >= 0 && (*A)[i][j-1] == 1) {
         size += visit(A, i, j-1, n, m, 0);
     }
     if(j+1 < m && (*A)[i][j+1] == 1) {
         size += visit(A, i, j+1, n, m, 0);
     }
     if(i+1 < n && j-1 >= 0 && (*A)[i+1][j-1] == 1) {
         size += visit(A, i+1, j-1, n, m, 0);
     }
     if(i+1 < n && (*A)[i+1][j] == 1) {
         size += visit(A, i+1, j, n, m, 0);
     }
     if(i+1 < n && j+1 < m && (*A)[i+1][j+1] == 1) {
         size += visit(A, i+1, j+1, n, m, 0);
     }
     return size; 
}
```

What does `***A` mean?

Comment: You even didn't care to tell us the language..

Comment: Ohh!..My bad..It's C++.

Comment: Put a tag so C++ guys can find it

Comment: Done Sir.Now, can you please tell me why we are passing 'A' as '***A' .What's it's advantages?

Comment: Nope, I am no master at c++

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087113/how-many-levels-of-pointers-can-we-have try this maybe

Comment: But still, thank you sir for taking your time and correcting me.

Answer (score 0):

> "*Please tell me the difference between functions accepting arrays using single, double or triple pointers.*"

Arrays (`int[]` for example) will change to (`int*`) during compile time...

*For example,* take an integer `int some_num = 10;`

Now what would you do when you suddenly want to store these numbers as an array, of course `int[] some_num_array = { some_num, some_num2, some_num3 };` <-- *This is the most general method to do this...*

If you know about [vectors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), then the vector equivalent would be: `std::vector<int> some_num_array{ some_num, some_num2, some_num3 }`...

And you probably already know what a vector does, it is a *container* that stores values inside it and of course it can never store infinite value since it eats up your memory and will become as large as your memory can handle...

This, `int*** A` that you have asked, can be interpreted as `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>`...

As you can already see, it is **a vector** *containing vectors* **of vectors**...

Then, the same way, it is **a pointer** *containing pointers* **of pointers** as well...

The *reference operator (&)* is used to convert a pointer to a super-pointer and so-on... And in C/C++ referencing means to allow other members and functions to assign a value to a variable (*Remember! You can never assign to a variable, ever!*)...

If we would try to convert our number `some_num` above to an `int***`, it means converting a non-pointer variable to a 3-level pointer that will have 5 as its value... `auto A = new int**(new int*(&some_num));`

So in other words, `int***` can be termed as a three-dimensional pointer (array), just like you have seen a two-dimensional array storing columns inside its *rows* (indices).

A three-dimensional array, on the other hand, stores multiple two-dimensional arrays inside itself (*sides*)...

> "*What does ***A mean?*"

Here, you can confuse people with a term which is known a [**de**referencing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access#Dereference) and does quite the opposite of referencing, the fact which we were talking about all this time... it **de**references (reducing [Hence, usage of **de** inside the term] the so-called *pointer-level* one-by-one)...

Like so, `some_num = ***A;`, which just stores the value of **A** inside **some_num**

But, `***A = some_num;`, on the other hand, is different, it changes the value of **A** anywhere but **NOT** the pointer itself, that is the reason why `(const char)*` cannot be dereferenced for assignment, since its dereferenced value is a constant character, which **is a constant...**... (inside or outside the function)

So, lastly, I would conclude by saying that the usage of pointers is either to be able to *dereference* its value (modifying the value, but not the pointer) or creating an array of a memory-based limit of levels of pointers...